# How to consistently define list of options to use as enum, int and string at the same time?

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, c-preprocessor, compile-time

I am providing an example with display resolutions but the question is more general.

Let say we have following configurations: 640x480; 1024x768; 1600x900. If they are defined separately it would look something like:

```
std::string RESTR[] = { "640x480", "1024x768", "1600x900" };
struct Enum { enum ERes { _640x480, _1024x768, _1600x900 }; };
uint RES[][2] = { { 640, 480 }, { 1024, 768 }, { 1600, 900 } };
```

It is too error prone to maintain all of the lists. It should be given the following way (or at least something very similar):

```
Res(  640, 480 )
Res( 1024, 768 )
Res( 1600, 900 )
```

A Resolution class would seem to be a fine solution, it behaves as a string when needed and returns a value in other use cases. But it does not have the enums before running the application. In order to utilize resolution enums in development a compile time magic, preprocessor or template definition is required. How could it be resolved?

Is there a standard state-of-art approach for this kind of problem?

Comment: Please google "c++ enum string representation"

Comment: I can define strings and enums at once, but the int representation is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different approaches to solve problems of the such kind using only C++ tools (both of them use preprocessor's macros):

1. The approach based on [variadic macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro) (you can write your own code or use [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) library macros).
2. The approach based on [X-macro technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro).

Second approach is good for you if you use C++03 or lower (first one is available if you use C++11 or higher or if your C++ compiler supports C99). Here is its description:

- Create an include file **without include guards** (you may give it an extension different from your usual header file extension, e.g. `inc`) with the name `Resolution` and the following contents:

  ```
  RESOLUTION(  640, 480 )
  RESOLUTION( 1024, 768 )
  RESOLUTION( 1600, 900 )
  ```
- Define your arrays as follows:

  ```
  #define TO_STRING_LITERAL_(S) #S
  #define TO_STRING_LITERAL(S) TO_STRING_LITERAL_(S)
  #define STRING_RESOLUTION_(X, Y) X ## x ## Y
  #define STRING_RESOLUTION(X, Y) TO_STRING_LITERAL(STRING_RESOLUTION_(X, Y)),
  #define ENUM_RESOLUTION(X, Y) _ ## X ## x ## Y,
  #define INT_RESOLUTION(X, Y) { X , Y },

  #define RESOLUTION(X, Y) STRING_RESOLUTION(X, Y)
  std::string RESTR[] =
  {
  #    include "Resolution.inc"
  };
  #undef RESOLUTION

  #define RESOLUTION(X, Y) ENUM_RESOLUTION(X, Y)
  struct Enum
  {
       enum ERes
       {
  #        include "Resolution.inc"
       };
  };
  #undef

  #define RESOLUTION(X, Y) INT_RESOLUTION(X, Y)
  uint RES[][2] =
  {
  #   include "Resolution.inc"
  };
  #undef
  ```

**Update:** [**@rici**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici) suggests in comments an interesting simplification of the `STRING_RESOLUTION` macro:

```
#define STRING_RESOLUTION(X, Y) #X "x" #Y
```

It is possible because a series of string literals is recognized as a one literal by a C++ compiler: `"string1" "string2" "string3" == "string1string2string3"`.

Comment: For the string, I'd suggest the simpler `#define STRING_RESOLUTION(X, Y) #X "x" #Y`. It is not, in general, possible to ##-concat string pieces together, and it is useful to remember that it is almost never necessary either.

Comment: It seems the trick I was lacking was the `undef` so that macro `RESOLUTION` is used for multiple purposes. Very cunning and thank you for giving the broader C++03- answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not married to using an `enum`, you can use something along the lines of:

```
#define CONCAT2(A, B) A ## B
#define CONCAT(A, B) CONCAT2(A, B)

#define STR2(A) #A
#define STR(A) STR2(A)

#define DEFINE_RESOLUTION(ResClass, X, Y) \
   struct ResClass { \
      static const int val = CONCAT(0x, CONCAT(X, Y)); \
      static char const* toString() \
      { \
         return STR(CONCAT(X, CONCAT(x, Y))); \
      } \
      static int getX() { return (X); } \
      static int getY() { return (Y); } \
   };
```

```
DEFINE_RESOLUTION(Res1, 640, 480);
DEFINE_RESOLUTION(Res2, 1024, 768);

// Test the code
#include <iostream>    

int getint()
{
   return Res1::val;
   // return Res2::val;
}

int main()
{
   int v = getint();
   switch (v)
   {
      case Res1::val:
         std::cout << Res1::getX() << "\n";
         std::cout << Res1::getY() << "\n";
         std::cout << Res1::toString() << "\n";
         break;

      case Res2::val:
         std::cout << Res2::getX() << "\n";
         std::cout << Res2::getY() << "\n";
         std::cout << Res2::toString() << "\n";
         break;

      default:
         std::cout << "Got default\n";

   }
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
640
480
640x480
```